# PHP equivalent of runat="server" in ASP.NET

Tags: php

I'm trying to access an element in PHP by its ID. The problem is that PHP doesn't have `runat` property like `ASP.NET` and I couldn't find any solution in Google. Is there a way to do this in PHP?

```
<div id='content' runat="server"></div>

content.innerHTML = "blablabla";
```

Comment: Better describe what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent for this in PHP. PHP mindset of a programmer is a lot diffrent to the one of ASP.NET programmer. In ASP.NET client and server side are more connected since you have little or no control over the HTML that is produced at the end. In PHP you connect the client and server side using standard HTML forms for POST and GET methods. For other stuff you should use javascript (I would recommend the JQuery library) to trigger a POST or AJAX request to server and to update the HTML.